# Using angular $scope and ng-model for number adjustment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a metronome and initially had a div set up with a value of 100:

```
<div ng-bind="currentBpm"></div>
```

In my controller I had the scope initially set:

```
$scope.currentBpm = 100;
```

I then also have a function that adjusts the tempo:

```
function adjustBpm(direction) {
    if (direction == false && $scope.currentBpm > 1) {
        $scope.currentBpm = $scope.currentBpm -1;
    } else if (direction == true && $scope.currentBpm < 999) {
        $scope.currentBpm = $scope.currentBpm +1;
    }

    console.log($scope.currentBpm);
}
```

This worked well, but I need to give the user the option of entering a value using the numeric keyboard.

Switching the div to a number input:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currentBpm">
```

Allows the user to click the input and adjust the value, but the $scope is then not used. The function for adjusting the value still console logs the previous value and not that of the input. Im guessing ng-model moves away from the scope and creates 2 different values.

Is there any way to sync these up?

The adjustBpm function is called on a click of a + / - button.

```
<div ng-click="adjustBpm(false)"> + </div>
```

Comment: How and where you calling `adjustBpm`?Create plunker for it

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN just updated the question and and Ill see what I can do.

Comment: @Lovelock Just to make sure. does the above code work if you use '<button>' instead of '<div>"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). Follow the rule of always adding a dot (`.`) to ng-models.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call ng-click and ng-keyup on the input :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currentBpm" ng-click="adjustBpm(false)" ng-keyup="adjustBpm(false)">
```

Or as said @georgeawg you can use ng-change :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currentBpm" ng-change="adjustBpm(false)">
```

Comment: The [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) would be more appropriate.